# Symfony2: How to restrict access to Login page by registered users

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have a Symfony2 App with an independent login page. 
Here is a snapshot of my `security.yml`

```
# defaut login area for standard users
        main:
            pattern:            .*
            form_login:
                provider:       fos_userbundle
                login_path:     /auth/login
                use_referer:    true
                check_path:     /auth/login_check
                always_use_default_target_path: false
                default_target_path: gd_top_merchants
            logout:
                path:           /auth/logout
                target:         /
            anonymous:          true

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_SONATA_ADMIN]
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    access_control:
        # URL of FOSUserBundle which need to be available to anonymous users
        - { path: ^/_wdt, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/_profiler, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }

        # -> custom access control for the admin area of the URL
```

Now if a logged in user types /auth/login he gets access to the login page. I don't want this to happen. 
How can I accomplish this?

I am using the `JMSSecurityExtra` bundle with the `JMSDiExtra` bundle.

I have not extended any of the `FOSUserBundle` controllers yet. Is there a way to solve my problem without overriding the `loginAction`?

Comment: See my answer from this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667091/symfony2-access-for-login-and-register-page-for-anonymous-only-not-users/13744110#13744110

Comment: @lifo This was a long time back! Yes, I solved it by overriding the login action too.