# Symfony protecting routes

Tags: symfony

Can someone explain why I can access login route when I'm already logged in even though I've set in `security.yaml` for only anonymous users to access the route?

```
access_control:
     - { path: ^/login, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
```

How can I prevent from accessing this route when I'm logged in ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Symfony2 - Access for Login and Register page for Anonymous only not Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13667091/symfony2-access-for-login-and-register-page-for-anonymous-only-not-users)

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security.html#securing-other-services) how security works.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your first question, the user always has the `IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY` role, even when it's authenticated.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/access_control.html